# TYPO3: Strict Standards: Non-static method / Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: php, apache, typo3, fatal-error, extbase

I have googled so much and tried everything but can't get behind this. A client installed an extension on TYPO3 and we get the following error message in the backend and frontend.

> Strict Standards: Non-static method t3lib_div::getClassName() should not be called statically in /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php on line 5033
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 't3lib_error_Exception' with message 'PHP Runtime Notice: Non-static method t3lib_div::getClassName() should not be called statically in /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php line 5033' in /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/t3lib/error/class.t3lib_error_errorhandler.php:106 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php(5033): t3lib_error_ErrorHandler->handleError(2048, 'Non-static meth...', '/homepages/25/d...', 5033, Array) #1 /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php(5033): t3lib_div::getClassName() #2 /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php(143): t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_error_Pro...') #3 /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/index.php(80): require('/homepages/25/d...') #4 {main} thrown in /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/typo3_src-4.3.14/t3lib/error/class.t3lib_error_errorhandler.php on line 106

Trying to log into the install tool gives this error message

> Fatal error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility' not found in /homepages/25/d322968656/htdocs/ravati/typo3/typo3conf/ext/ke_questionnaire/ext_localconf.php on line 6

Any ideas for a TYPO3 beginner? :(((

Comment: Please give us a little more information about the system you are using. The filepaths of your error messages imply that your installation is VERY old, ancient to be precise. It is saying that the version of TYPO3 you are using is 4.3. The current one is 8.7. All versions below 7.6 are not supported anymore, so you are strongly advised to update, before doing anything else with it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's a 4.3 typo3-version. I know it's ancient but for now it'd great to just get the page running again. Can't I just get rid of that extension and everything will be fine? Somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a PHP version related error. Which PHP version do you use? Beware that this ancient TYPO3 version only works with an ancient PHP version. :)

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your comment. It's version 5.6. I already tried to update it to 7.6 but this didn't work.

Comment: With PHP 5.6 you are too up-to-date. I think, PHP 5.2 or 5.3 would work better.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of that. I set up PHP 5.2 et voila... it works. Thanks a lot for your (and everybody's) help :)))

Answer (score 0):

i presume your client tried to install ke_questionnaire and ignored all warnings. Make a copy of your /typo3conf/localconf.php, then open the original file and look for every appearence of ke_questionnaire and delete it. Be careful not to destroy the php syntax! Then delete every file which begins with "temp_cach ..." in /typo3conf/ and delete the folder /typo3conf/ke_questionnaire

The page should work now ...

BUT: your installation is old. I mean really old. There is no possibilty to install any extension from the TER anymore. Dont do this, it will kill your installation everytime. In addition: this version of TYPO3 is not save anymore, it is only a question of time that anybody will hack it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried it right away but it didn't work. I get the same error messages :/ Hereby I get the same error message for the install tool as for the backend and frontend.

Comment: Info: deleting the temp_CACHE*-files doesn't really work. After I refresh the page, they are back in typo3conf/
Now I'm trying this solution:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/18111